# VSCode jsx expression formatting

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

Hi I have a format in my existing code I want to change it to a different format, but cannot understand how to do it? if there is any eslint or prettier rules please suggest:
The current format is:

```
                    {this.state.creatingNew && (
                        <Button color="primary" variant="contained" type="submit">
                            Poslať
                        </Button>
                    )}
                    <Button size="large" color="secondary" variant="contained" onClick={() => this.cancelEditing()}>
                        Zrušiť
                    </Button>
```

My desired format is:

```
{this.state.creatingNew && <Button color="primary" type="submit" style={{ width: '140px', marginRight: '10px' }}>Poslať</Button>}
<Button color="danger" type="button" onClick={() => this.cancelEditing()} style={{ width: '140px', marginRight: '10px' }}>Zrušiť</Button>
```

This is my `.prettierrc.json`:

```
{
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "useTabs": false,
    "semi": true,
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 140,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "arrowParens": "avoid",
    "proseWrap": "never"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prettier is opinionated by nature so if you are unable to tweak it by changing the few [options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) it has, then you have to either agree to its style or look for an alternative.